# Build and Archive - nothing happens on Submit Application

Tags: iphone, build, app-store, distribution, submission

After successfully building the distribution version of my app for submission to iTunes Connect, I selected Build and Archive, as recommended, and the Organizer window popped up. Why, wondered I. OK, if I click the Archived Applications tab it displays one archived application (unfortunately grayed out - don't know if that means anything. I mark it and click Submit to iTunes Connect, XCode asks for credentials - and nothing happens. OK, says I, I will add the app manually via the browser, and right-click it and select 'Reveal in Finder'. I go hunting for files created recently, and find nothing.

How are you supposed to submit apps, really?? :)

I followed the iOS dev guide for Distribution, [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW2).

I would also like it confirmed that submitting from within XCode allows me to log onto iTunes Connect and add screenshots etc, this is my first app for Appstore.

Update: Apparently it ends up in username/Library/MobileDevice/Archived Applications/somelongnumber - on the second go it revealed it in Finder. I updated the title, since I now have some files ;)

To clarify, I was expecting some kind of upload progress bar after supplying the credentials, followed by 'your app has been submitted to iTunes Connect' or similar.

Is this a common problem? Will uploading manually be possible now? I guess iTunes Connect will tell me what files to upload if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is a common mistake due to Apple's unhelpful UI.

Before validating and submitting your app via Xcode's Organizer, you must login to iTunes connect and submit all the information about your app (description, screen shots, etc.).  Once you've submitted everything but the binary via iTunes Connect, your app will be in a "Waiting for Upload" state.  Now if you go into Organizer and click "Validate Application..." you'll get a response.  Once your app has been validated, you can click "Submit Application to iTunes Connect..." and cross your fingers for a quick acceptance.

Comment: Yes, at least some kind of response if something fails would have been helpful. I set up the app in iTunes Connect and downloaded the "app loader", used the same Submit app button in the XCode Organizer again, and I got the message it was submitted to Appstore. Thanks cduhn :)